# MFC application crashes on Windows XP

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++

I have a very strange problem with my MFC application. Details:

- Built with Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 (Version 9.0.30729.1 SP) under Windows Vista SP1 Ultimate.

This app. is about 15 years old and has seen most VS versions.

I have a separate test-pc with: Windows XP Pro SP3, Vista Home Premium, 7 Ultimate.

Of course I installed the VC++ redistributable on all Windows.

Now I will try to describe the problem:

The program uses MFC classes for working with CArchive objects. A user can create a new project that contains one or more sheets that contain cells that may contain text, pictures, or both. e.g. a sheet with an 8x8 grid. This project can be saved to disk: MySheet.K01, MySheet.K02, etc. The sheets are viewed with a CMultiDocTemplate.

I created a branch of this project for creating a program that can convert these files to another format. I made it a console application using AllocConsole().

When I test the program, the results are that it works fine on Windows 7, partially under Windows Vista and nothing but crashes on Windows XP.

I have ruled out the possibility that it matters if the program is compiled under Windows XP.

Here is what I think is what is going wrong:

```
CFile   myFile;
CMyDoc    *pDoc = (CMyDoc *)m_pDocViewTemplate->CreateNewDocument(); // Get a CDocument and cast it
CFileException myError;
TCHAR   *arcFileName = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];

BOOL bTmp = myFile.Open(arcFileName, CFile::modeRead, &myError);
char lpszError[1024];
myError.GetErrorMessage(lpszError, 1024, 0);
_cprintf(lpszError);
_cprintf("\n");
if(!bTmp)
{
 _cprintf("ERROR: Unable to open the file!\n");
 return;
}

myFile.SeekToBegin();
CArchive myArc(&myFile, CArchive::load, 8192, 0);
myArc.m_bForceFlat = TRUE;
myArc.m_pDocument = pDoc;

pDoc->Serialize(myArc);
```

I am really at a loss here. I can provide more details if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

arcFileName will contain something like: "C:\MyProject\MySheet.K01"

Obviously...

Answer (score 0):

It crashes when run from the IDE on XP? What crash do you get? Does it crash in Debug and Release versions?